# Trying to create a form in php but error

Tags: php

this is part of my contact form

I want to make it so that it validates ONLY IF someone enters a telephone number

here's what I have tried

```
$telephone = $_POST['Telephone_Number'];

$telephone_exp = '/^[+]?([\d]{0,3})?[\.\-\s]?([\d]3)[\.\-\s]*([\d]{3})[\.\-\s]?([\d]{4})$/';
if ($telephone > 0) && (preg_match($telephone_exp, $telephone))
{
    $error_message .= 'The Telephone Number you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
```

Comment: okay can you give me some hint ??it would be really great

Answer (score 2):

Try doing it like:

```
$telephone = $_POST['Telephone_Number'];

$telephone_exp = '/^[+]?([\d]{0,3})?[\.\-\s]?([\d]3)[\.\-\s]*([\d]{3})[\.\-\s]?([\d]{4})$/';
if (isset($_POST['Telephone_Number']) && preg_match($telephone_exp, $telephone))
{
    $error_message .= 'The Telephone Number you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct syntax

```
if ($telephone > 0 && preg_match($telephone_exp, $telephone)){
}
```

you had

```
if ($telephone > 0) && (preg_match($telephone_exp, $telephone))
```

Comment: okay let me try and thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add an `if( !empty($telephone) )` before the validation. This way, the validation will only execute if the telephone value was provided.

Answer (score 0):

The error is only typing, with parenthesis.

Correct: `if (($telephone > 0) && (preg_match($telephone_exp, $telephone)))`

Wrong: `if ($telephone > 0) && (preg_match($telephone_exp, $telephone))`